# Can I make parameters mandatory without creating a parameter block for every function?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to have powershell make every parameter for every function in a file mandatory without having to add a parameter block to every single function?

Comment: You have to tell PowerShell which parameters are mandatory for each function (yes, for each one). There is not a feature like the one you imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you're going to have to add `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]` to all of your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that you need the same parameters across a lot of different functions? One thing I am trying to do to simplify my scripts is if a task is happening a lot of times throughout my module, I am making it into it's own function and then calling the function instead of creating the same logic over and over.